# What syntax errors are causing the 'text' of the function to be returned in this JS closure, rather than having it increment?

Tags: javascript, closures, increment

I am simply trying to create an incrementing function, and I am having zero luck. I can only manage to get this type of output, or I get an integer that doesn't increment.

```js
const count = () => {
  let countUp = function(n) {
    return function() {
      n += 1;
      return n;
    }
  };
  return countUp;
};

console.log(count());
```

Output:

```
function(n) {
    return function() {
      n += 1;
      return n;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you expect `return countUp;` to do? Without `()` that's not a function call, it's just a reference to the function.

Comment: @Pointy - I am trying to get an integer to increment every time `count();` is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an ES5 script that will increment a counter each time it's called. The code below makes use of [immediately invoked function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
//The number we want to start counting up from
var startAt = 0;

//Immediately invoke the anonymous outer function - this will return a function into our "count" variable. The closure will retain access to local variable j which is passed as an argument.
var count = (function(i) {
  var j = i;
  return function() {
    j += 1;
    return j;
  }
}(startAt));

//Call count 10 times
var k;
for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
  console.log(count());
}
```

Below is the same code written using more terse ES6 syntax:

```js
const count = ((i) => {
  var j = i;
  return () => ++j;
})(0);

for (let k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
  console.log(count());
}
```